# argv error when integrating MWFeedParser

Tags: ios

I am trying desperately to integrate MWFeedParser in my application. My application uses storyboards, and one UIviewController should show the table view with the RSS. I copied all the files from the MWfeedParser to my project by drag and drop. I then added them to the compile source section and made sure that they where compatible to ARC. Then in my stroyboard I dragged a UITableViewController and set it to RootViewController class.

The result:

as soon as the app launches I get this error:

[image]

I get the error even if there is no UITableViewcontroller in the storyboard linked to that class. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoint to see on which particular line the app crashes.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?